# executing java/scala code in scala.html templates

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

Can I execute that line of code

```
nav = request().path().toString()
```

inside of scala template like index.scala.html

I would like to have that code to check on witch side is user and to mark it on menu
using code like this in main.scala.html:

```
                        <li class="@("active".when(nav == "contact"))">
                        <a href="">Contacts</a>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you different approach, create tag - resuable template, which takes Integer as an argument,
it will render menu and mark as an active different menuitem depends on value.

```
@(menuItem: Int)    
<ul >
           <li  @if(menuItem==1){ class="active" } >
               ////
           </li>
           <li @if(menuItem==2){ class="active" }>               
           </li>
           <li @if(menuItem==3){ class="active" }>               
               ///
           </li>        
</ul>
```

from your contact page and any other page, call this tag with corresponding value, `@views.html.tags.menu(1)`

Comment: Why an int? If you use ints than you have to keep a table in your head which int corresponds to which menu item. Thats not a good practice imho.

Also if you have several menuitems I would use match and not many ifs.

But I agree that a reusable Tag is good...

Comment: It can be any value, base on this value corresponding menu item will be activated, you could use pattern matching as well. My point is that you should use reusable template which would render menu, and invoke it from different pages (like contact).

Answer (score 1):

You can define variables like that if that is your question. If it is not your question than please try to explain your problem in more detail.

```
@nav = { @request().path().toString() }
```

Comment: Hey. thanks. it Helps me with setting up a variable @nav
this code
[code]@nav = { @request().path().toString() }[/code] 
works. 
But now I would like to use it in "when statment" in code as follow
[code]
                        <li class="@("active".when(nav == "/pomoc"))">

[/code]
But it dosent work.
When I use variable with '@' char I am getting error:
" illegal start of simple expression "
Please help

Comment: Have your printed request().path().toString to see if the string corresponds to your expectation?